# Parse Attributes from Java Files using Java Parser

Tags: java, javaparser

I have 3 classes below.

```
public class A {
     B b;
}

public class B {
    C c;

    public C getC() {
        A a;
        return c;
    }
}

public class C {

}
```

I want to parse the classes using java parser having following info:

- Class names
- Method names
- Attribute names

Comment: Well, then, uh, do it. Also, what parser implementation will that be?

Comment: I want to use Java Parser (Japa Parser).
Source Link:
https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to start from the most recent version of JavaParser available on GitHub: https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser

You can easily create a project using Maven and including among the dependencies JavaParser:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaparser-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Then to parse a file is very easy:

```
 File sourceFile = new File("path/to/my/file.java");
 CompilationUnit compilationUnit = JavaParser.parse(sourceFile);
```

JavaParser returns the root node of the Abstract Syntax Tree which is a CompilationUnit and represents all the contents of a file. You just need to navigate this tree and extract the information.

For example from a CompilationUnit you can get the top types (but not the internal classes) using the method [getTypes](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/2.2.1/com/github/javaparser/ast/CompilationUnit.html#getTypes--) which will return a list of [TypeDeclaration](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/2.2.1/com/github/javaparser/ast/body/TypeDeclaration.html). A TypeDeclaration can be either a class, an interface or an enum. TypeDeclaration has the method getName that you can use to get the name of the declared type. You could then ask the members of a TypeDeclaration and look for internal classes, methods or fields.

Other two ways to navigate the tree are:
 * using visitors
 * using the method [getChildrenNodes](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/2.2.1/com/github/javaparser/ast/Node.html#getChildrenNodes--) which is available on every node (CompilationUnit, TypeDeclaration, methods declarations, statements etc.)

To use the visitor pattern check the package [visitor](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/2.2.1/com/github/javaparser/ast/visitor/package-frame.html) in JavaParser: there are already several abstract visitors to extend. Once you have created your visitor you can just invoke it using `compilationUnit.accept(myVisitor, <extra arg>);` and it will crawl the whole tree.

If you want to use the getChildrenNodes instead you can do something along these lines:

```
void processNode(Node node) {
   if (node instanceof TypeDeclaration) {
      // do something with this type declaration
   } else if (node instanceof MethodDeclaration) {
      // do something with this method declaration
   } else if (node instanceof FieldDeclaration) {
      // do something with this field declaration
   }
   for (Node child : node.getChildrenNodes()){
      processNode(child);
   }
}

...
CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(sourceFile);
processNode(node);
...
```

Hope it helps and if you have other questions specific to JavaParser feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/issues/new) or join the [JavaParser chat](https://gitter.im/javaparser/javaparser?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge).

Disclaimer: I am a contributor of the JavaParser project

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
For my above code, I still can not parse field names.
Could you please help me?