# How to include JavaParser Dependencies with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, javaparser

I read the official http://javaparser.org/ page but I don't know how to install it.
I saw this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215185/7643663 that told me to

> easily create a project using Maven and including among the dependencies JavaParser

along with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaparser-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But I don't know how to build my code using javaparser with maven.
I executed `mvn clean install` in the directory I downloaded the javaparser source code with no errors.
Then I tried to run the following:

```
import com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.*;

public class PreprocessJavaparser {

    public static void listClasses() {
        CompilationUnit compilationUnit = JavaParser.parse("class A { }");
        ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration classA = compilationUnit.getClassByName("A");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        listClasses();
    }
}
```

But when I import `com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.*;` I get this error: `package com.github.javaparser.JavaParser does not exist`.
So I think I didn't install JavaParser correctly or I have to deal somehow with the JavaParser Dependencies in a pom.xml.

Here is my pom.xml with the javaparser-core dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>preprocess</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaparser-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: are you using an IDE as well? it may need to be refreshed to reflect recent file changes

Comment: Show some of your code including imports. My guess is that some of your imports are not correct.

Comment: Are you running `mvn clean install` where pom.xml (where javaparser-core dependency is added)  exists?

Comment: Can you share the entire pom.xml content?

Comment: I added my code as @lexicore suggested.

Comment: @WilliamReed I don't use an IDE.

Comment: @ankitkpd There comes an pom.xml with the download of the sources with no  javaparser-core dependency included.

Comment: @vahdet I added my pom.xml which is in the same directory as my provided code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I executed mvn clean install in the directory I downloaded the javaparser source code with no errors.

No, you should not do that. The whole point of maven is that it takes the compiled version of a library (e.g. JavaParser), download it and let you use it in your own project. It means that unless you want to change JavaParser itself (you do not want to) you do not need to download the source code of JavaParser.

Just create your own project and add JavaParser as a dependency to that project. That is it.

Answer (score 1):

Your import is wrong:

```
import com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.*;
```

You try to import from the `JavaParser` class as if it were a package.

Should be

```
import com.github.javaparser.JavaParser;
```

Or

```
import com.github.javaparser.*;
```

For all the classes/packages you use.

> @WilliamReed I don't use an IDE. – AIpeter

Well, maybe you should, it will help you with this sort of problems.

Another problem is here:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaparser-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

You should use `dependencies`, not `dependencyManagement/dependencies`. The latter only declares dependencies, does not actually use them.

Comment: When I try `import com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.;` or `import com.github.javaparser.*;` I still get the same error `error: package com.github.javaparser does not exist`.

Comment: If you build it with Maven, why do you call `javac`?